# Use of locators in Katalon mobile automation

Tags: testing, mobile, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I am using Katalon for mobile automation and my question is can I use locators like XPath or CSS directly like we do in Appium or are we restricted to using the `findobject` locator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the test object with any properties and then use the `Mobile.*` keywords. Like this

```
TestObject myObject = new TestObject().addProperty('xpath', ConditionType.EQUALS, '//xpath-path')
Mobile.tap(myobject, 1)
```

You will need to import TestObject and ConditionType classes. You can just press Ctrl+Shift+O in script mode and Katalon will do the rest.

Or, add the following at the beginning of the test script:

```
com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType as ConditionType
com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
```

Comment: I am getting difficulty while executing this can you please elaborate with example code.

Comment: What difficulty are you having?

Comment: Getting this failure Reason:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ConditionType for class: Script1554199129353

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. You will need to import TestObject and ConditionType classes. You can just press Ctrl+Shift+O in script mode and Katalon will do the rest.